# How to generate a column of unique IDs (UUIDs) in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, uuid

How to insert a column of unique codes (UUIDs) in LibreOffice?

If that's not possible with LibreOffice itself, how could one generate UUIDs in a way so that they can be simply copy and pasted into a column in LibreOffice on GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this formula from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41026697/11443568).

```
=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4))
```

Note that a new UUID will be generated if you close then open the file (using the formula on the UUID column). My advice is to use the formula to generate the UUID, copy the generated UUID and paste it to the appropriate column.

If you have powershell on your machine you can use the following to generate 10 UUIDs (change the value of `$i` to the number you desire). Copy them, then paste them to the appropriate column.

```ps
$i = 10

While( $i -gt 0){

    $a = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    Write-Host $a
    $i = $i - 1
}
```

Comment: How can only apply the formula? I tried it by clicking on a column (also tried it on a cell) -> Insert -> Function -> entered the formula (with one preceding =). It then shows `Error: 501`. If I save and reopen the file it shows `Error: 509`. LOC version is 7.0.4.2. Edit: had to switch language to English first; LOC should fix that so it works across languages.